# Django: Redirect to previous page after login

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a simple website with login functionality very similar to the one here on SO.
The user should be able to browse the site as an anonymous user and there will be a login link on every page. When clicking on the login link the user will be taken to the login form. After a successful login the user should be taken back to the page from where he clicked the login link in the first place.
I'm guessing that I have to somehow pass the url of the current page to the view that handles the login form but I can't really get it to work.

EDIT:
I figured it out. I linked to the login form by passing the current page as a GET parameter and then used 'next' to redirect to that page. Thanks!

EDIT 2:
My explanation did not seem to be clear so as requested here is my code:
Lets say we are on a page foo.html and we are not logged in. Now we would like to have a link on foo.html that links to login.html. There we can login and are then redirected back to foo.html.
The link on foo.html looks like this:

```
      <a href='/login/?next={{ request.path }}'>Login</a>
```

Now I wrote a custom login view that looks somewhat like this:

```
def login_view(request):
   redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get('next', '')
   if request.method=='POST':
      #create login form...
      if valid login credentials have been entered:
         return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)  
   #...
   return render_to_response('login.html', locals())
```

And the important line in login.html:

```
<form method="post" action="./?next={{ redirect_to }}">
```

So yeah thats pretty much it, hope that makes it clear.

Comment: I think the Django login stuff handles that for you, is it not working for you?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You do not need to make an extra view for this, the functionality is already built in.

First each page with a login link needs to know the current path, and the easiest way is to add the request context preprosessor to settings.py (the 4 first are default), then the request object will be available in each request:

**settings.py:**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

Then add in the template you want the Login link:

**base.html:**

```
<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>
```

This will add a GET argument to the login page that points back to the current page.

The login template can then be as simple as this:

**registration/login.html:**

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="">
  {{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I personally use this solution, but the one modification I would make is that it fails if `request.path` is null, so I make it `{% firstof request.path '/' %}`, that way if the request path isn't available for some reason the user gets sent to the home page.

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution but, when django.contrib.auth.views.login redirects (after authenticates succesfully) the instance of User is not in the request, so user.is_authenticated() always returns False. Any help?

Comment: Adding on top of @jorelli, you can use named URL and do `<a href="{% url auth_login %}?next={% firstof request.path '/' %}">Login</a>` instead.

Comment: You also have to watch out for if a user logs in after just logging out. In other words, the `next` would be something like `/accounts/logout/` and after the user log ins, he will immediately be logged back out lol, and the loop continues.

Comment: @jorelli request.path won't be null at all, I don't see the sense of this.

Comment: I found that this only worked when I added the following to the login form on Django 1.5: <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />

Comment: Could this be used for a package such as `django-allauth`?

Comment: @hobbes3 How could I handle this loop then? I mean, if the previous page is logout page...

Comment: **NOTE:**

If you get a error something like 

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.context_processors'`

Do NOT add this line 

`"django.core.context_processors.request",` in *settings.py* .

Because in newer version this following line is given by default by Django and it will handle this task. 

`'django.template.context_processors.request'`

Answer (score 33):

To support full urls with param/values you'd need:

```
?next={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}
```

instead of just:

```
?next={{ request.path }}
```

Comment: Actually this is not a good idea, you will find the query string very very long if you have too many clicks

Answer (score 30):

This may not be a "best practice", but I've successfully used this before:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/'))
```

Comment: This has a weak point - some users/browsers have passing referer turned off

Comment: There's also the problem in the case where a user arrives at a form, fills in the information and then submits. The HTTP_REFERER is then the form page's URL, and not the URL of the page the user came from in the first place.

Answer (score 14):

Django's built-in authentication works the way you want.

Their login pages include a `next` query string which is the page to return to after login.

Look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: Well, the login_required decorator would work just fine as it sets 'next' to whatever page I come from, but when using the decorator anonymous users cant view the site because they will be redirect to the login form right away. I think I just need to figure out how to set the value of 'next' to the url of the page the user comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I linked to the login form by passing the current page as a GET parameter and then used 'next' to redirect to that page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. This solution allows me to keep using the generic login view:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^accounts/profile/$', 'redirect_to', {'url': 'generic_account_url'}),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `registration/login.html` (nested within `templates` folder) if you insert the following line, the page will render like Django's original admin login page:

```
{% include "admin/login.html" %}
```

**Note: The file should contain above lines only.**

Answer (score -1):

See django docs for [views.login()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login), you supply a 'next' value (as a hidden field) on the input form to redirect to after a successful login.

Comment: Yes but how do I actually set 'next' to the page I come from?

Answer (score -3):

You can also do this

```
<input type="hidden" name="text" value="{% url 'dashboard' %}" />
```

Comment: Wrong answer, but name='next' seems feasible, not tested.