# Redirecting to last view after login

Tags: django, redirect

I have wrestled with this one for a bit and googled and looked through documentation, so I guess its time to ask. I am trying make my app redirect to the last viewed page after logging in. I am running django 1.2.4 and have had no luck so far.

This Stack Overflow thread seemed like it would do the trick but I have not had success with it: 
[Django: Redirect to previous page after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous)...

Currently after logging in from any view I am redirected to: //localhost:1100/accounts/profile/

settings.py has this suggested code: 
    "django.core.context_processors.request",

With this as my login button link: 
   `<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">login</a>`

I also made sure to import the RequestContext in my views.py file: 
    from django.template import RequestContext

I get the impression this is not working. Also I noticed now 
login URL has a partial next URL in it: 
//localhost:1100/accounts/login/?next=

Suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

As sdolan said, you can use the login_required decorator, but also there are a few more possiblities:

- Form action:

  ```
  <form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">
  ```
- Next hidden field:

  ```
   <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{request.path}}" />
  ```
- With a link to the login form:

  ```
  <a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>
  ```

For using them, you have to pass the Request Context in the corresponding view. Examples of doing this can be found here: http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/may/10/getting-requestcontext-your-templates/

Comment: +1 If you are using django stock login system, this method `href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>` is the most reliable one imo, other two methods are problematic because of [**this bug**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22288861/4334743).

Answer (score 4):

If you use the [`login_required`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator on your views, it will do this for you automatically.

This is confirmed by experience, and explained in the docs:

> If the user isn't logged in, redirect
>   to settings.LOGIN_URL, passing the
>   current absolute path in the query
>   string. Example:
>   /accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/.

Comment: Thanks sdolan, So I was using the text decorators in my views like such: @login_required
def wine_review_page(request, wine_id): Is this the incorrect way to go about this? I am not sure how to set the next link I guess.