# django, custom login, next url flushes after login attempt fails

Tags: python, django

I need to use my own login template, with django.contrib.auth.login.
I'm also trying to implement 'remember me' option, so I followed this snippet: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1881/

So my view looks like this:

```
def login_with_remember_me(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('remember_me', None):
            request.session.set_expiry(0)
    return login(request, template_name='domain/login.html')
```

Where 'login' is of course django.contrib.auth.views login view.

I also need user to be redirected to his previous page after login, so in my form I've added `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />`

And it works if user logs in successfully. But if he fails to login, the next parameter is flushed. How to get my redirect work in that case?

//edit
Ok, so I found dirty workaround:

```
def login_with_remember_me(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('remember_me', None):
            request.session.set_expiry(0)
    elif request.POST.get('next') is not None:
        kwargs['next'] = request.POST['next']
    return login(request, template_name='domain/login.html', *args, **kwargs)
```

But it looks awful. Can someone give me a better solution?

Comment: That might actually be a Django bug. it's probably getting `next` from `request.GET`, but in the error case it would be in `request.POST`.

Comment: But if I try to log in into django admin, it works fine. I checked django admin login template, it is also using hidden next input.

Comment: You were pretty close to right answer. The problem is, django is looking for next parameter in request.POST or request.GET, as you said. But in case of failure, we have GET method, but there is no request.GET['next'] parameter. Next URL is still in request.POST at this moment.

Comment: Exactly. When you submit the form with the password, everything, including the `next` parameter, is in `request.POST`. In case of failure, Django should repopulate the login form (including the `next` hidden field) from `request.POST`.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the next parameter in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post and by now I assume you've managed to solve it I would like to state one possible solution. You could change your template to look like:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% if request.POST.next %}{{ request.POST.next }}{% else %}{{ request.GET.next }}{% endif %}"/>
```

I think this should solve the issue of the "next" page being lost.