# Django: Redirect to previous page *with query string* after login

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using `django.contrib.auth` and would like to redirect to the previous page after logging in. I would like something like the following: [Django: Redirect to previous page after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login) *except* the redirected-to URL can contain a query string.

Currently I have the following link in my template:

```
<a href="{% url user_login %}?next={{ request.get_full_path }}">Login</a>
```

`user_login` is the name of my login view.

I would like to use [`{{ request.get_full_path }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) instead of `{{ request.path }}` to get the current path including the query string, but this would create a url with a query string within a query string (e.g. `/login/?next=/my/original/path/?with=other&fun=query&string=parameters`) which doesn't work.

I also tried adding a `redirect_to` argument to my login view and passing the url with the query string as a arument to the `url` template tag. However this gives me a `NoReverseMatch` error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about escaping the get parameters and then unquoting them in the view?

#### html

```
<a href="{% url user_login %}?next={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}">Login</a>
```

#### login view

```
if successful_login:
    url_with_get = urllib2.unquote(request.GET.get('next'))
    return http.HttpResponseRedirect(url_with_get)
```

PS: I've stumbled across your blog many times looking for PIP help : )