# Problem with redirecting to previous page after login in

Tags: django, templates, authentication, redirect

With this code:
urls.py

```
               url(r'^login/',
                   "django.contrib.auth.views.login"),
```

and tamplate like that:

```
<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>
```

which is redirecting to page with this code:

```
      {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
      <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
      </form>
      {% else %}
      <h1>Już jestes zalogowany chujku</h1>
      {% endif %}
```

I have context processor     `'django.core.context_processors.request'` but after login in I am redirected to

```
accounts/profile/
```

When I am on login page url is: `/accounts/login/?next=/gallery/newest/`. More, after login in it loged me in but I am still in `/accounts/login/?next=/gallery/newest/1/`.
Have I bugs in this code or answer is laying somewhere else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login

Comment: I saw this and do waht was in top rated answer, but something is not right.

Comment: Are you getting redirected to `accounts/profile/` when you manually type-in the login url or when you click on the login link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer. 
I think that this code did not use my own login.html template (but if i am wrong, please correct me):

```
url(r'^login/',
   "django.contrib.auth.views.login")
```

I change it to:

```
               url(r'^login/',
                   "django.contrib.auth.views.login", {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
```

Then I change my login.html tempalate code to:

```
  <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />

  </form>
```

I don't have the deeper meaning of what happend but this code which I copied here is working. Thanks for all for suggestions. It helps me to find answer and give a little better understanding of some things.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />` from your form, it makes django think that `next` variable is empty.

Comment: You're passing two values for `next`: one via GET and one via POST. Apparently, Django takes POST as predominant.