# Redirect to paginated page after form submit - Django

Tags: django, pagination, django-views

I use paginator to create a series of pages that meet certain criteria.
Each page contains a form that the user can submit.
When the form is submitted, I would like them to stay on/return to the page where they were.
How do I do that?
I've searched everywhere and read the docs, but can't find the answer.
I'm sure the problem is in front of the computer, but please help :)

Following is the view that should do this:

```
def assignment(request, pk):
"""View for each assignment"""
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    #### Get correct articles
    assignment = get_object_or_404(Assignment, pk=pk)
    country = assignment.country.ccode
    start_date = assignment.start_date
    end_date = assignment.end_date
    articles = Article.objects.filter(country=country).filter(pub_date__range=(start_date,end_date))
    paginator = Paginator(articles, 1)

    #### Pagination ####
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptryPage:
        articles = paginator(page(paginator.num_pages))

    #### Forms ####
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'event' in request.POST:
            event_form = EventRecordForm(request.POST, prefix='event')
            if event_form.is_valid():
                obj = event_form.save(commit=False)
                obj.article = paginator.page(page).object_list[0]
                obj.classified = True
                obj.coder = request.user.coder
                obj.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse ('coding:assignment', args=(pk,)))
            relevance_form = RelevanceCodingRecordForm(prefix='relevance')
        elif 'relevance' in request.POST:
            relevance_form = RelevanceCodingRecordForm(request.POST, prefix='relevance')
            if relevance_form.is_valid():
                obj = relevance_form.save(commit=False)
                obj.article = paginator.page(page).object_list[0]
                obj.screened = True
                obj.coder = request.user.coder
                obj.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse ('coding:assignment', args=(pk,)))
            event_form = EventRecordForm(prefix='event')
    else:
        event_form = EventRecordForm(prefix='event')
        relevance_form = RelevanceCodingRecordForm(prefix='relevance')


else:
    print ERROR
return render(request, 'coding/assignment.html', 
{'articles':articles,'assignment':assignment,'event_form':event_form,'relevance_form':relevance_form})
```

**Edit:**
Related suggested that I append `?next={{request.path}}` to my form action.
This doesn't work, however, since the paginator page is not included in the path. 
Doing what he suggested this happens:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/coding/assignment/1/?next=/coding/assignment/1/`
I did give paginator a second look though, and think that `?page={{ articles.number }}`should work, because in the example in the docs they do a link like this:
`<a href="?page={{ articles.next_page_number }}">next</a>`
However, this doesn't work.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think the page parameter should be in the request.path, so try appending this to the submit action in the template:

?next={{request.path}}

and make sure you have request as a template context processor in your settings.py file.
(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1711592/837845 for details)

Comment: Sadly it's not in the request.path, I've updated my question.
But thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

So to everyone struggling with redirecting to paginated page what i did was first for view of main page i store this page's pagination in session:

```
    request.session['previous_page'] = request.path_info + "?page=" + request.GET.get("page", '1')
```

Now in view that receives POST request from form return HttpResponseRedirect:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.session['previous_page'])
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I would like to thank you all for always driving me to the right direction in order to find answers to what is struggling me. After testing some of the proposed solutions concerning the current subject, I ended up in a similar way to return on the same paginated page that the submitting of the form was triggered and I would like to share it with everyone as it worked for me perfectly. I concluded that just by adding the following line in the redirection part of my view code would suffice, that is:

return redirect(request.path_info + "?page=" + str(paginated_page_obj.number) + "&")

Alternatively, the "request.path_info" could be replaced by the explicit url that is needed the redirection to be addressed to (ie: "'/url' + ....."), in case one wants to address to a different url than the current.

I hope my comment to be useful to someone.