# In Django, after login redirect the user to the previous page

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-validation

I want to secure each webpage of my django app, and what I want is that after login the user should be redirected to the previous page he was trying to access. So **in accounts/views.py** this is the login function I am using for that:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #some code

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect(request.POST.get('next','dashboard'))
        else:
            #some code

    else:
        #some code
```

Now, I have used `@login_required` condition for each view of my webapp in this way:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

**my login.html ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693342/django-after-login-required-redirect-to-next)):**

```
<form method="POST" action="/accounts/auth">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}" />
    {{ login_form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now if the user visits `accounts/profile` without login, then he is redirected to `accounts/login?next=/accounts/profile`, so after login he is successfully redirected to `accounts/profile` as the value of `'next'` is set to `/accounts/profile` and in login function if the user is authenticated then i have used `return redirect(request.POST.get('next','dashboard'))` which means redirect to the value of `next` if it is entered, otherwise `/accounts/dashboard`.

**Now coming to my issue,** if I try to access the login page directly (i.e. `/accounts/login`) then as there is no `next` variable in the URL, so according to my `login` function I should be redirected to `/accounts/dashboard` **but instead, I am getting the following error:** `Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` what am I doing wrong?

**Extra note**: I have even tried adding `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='dashboard'`  to my `settings.py` but still when the `next` variable is blank I am not redirected to the `dashboard`

**Mostly the mistake is in this piece of code:
`redirect(request.POST.get('next','dashboard'))`**

Comment: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` should be a URL path, so maybe `/dashboard`. See the docs here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

Comment: tried it, but I'm getting the same error `Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: Well that's a separate problem. That's something using the url resolvers without an argument to lookup. I'm guessing that's because `next` is being set as an empty string and then being used in the redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more defensive in your code to check for a value before sending it as the `redirect` location.

So assuming that you have a URL path named `dashboard` based on your code;

```py
path('accounts/dashboard/', Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
```

```py
from django.urls import reverse


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            next_param = request.POST.get('next')
            if next_param:
                url = next_param
            else:
                url = reverse('dashboard')

            return redirect(url)
```

Comment: this has a little problem, lets say i want to visit `accounts/profile` then the login url will be `accounts/login?next=/accounts/profile` and so after login i will be redirected to `accounts/dashboard?next=/accounts/profile`.

Comment: Yes, good point. My mistake. I've edited in the case there is a `next` value. You might want to consider how that value is added to the form to ensure that it's a valid URL to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out my mistake. Looking at the error `Reverse for "" not found. "" is not a valid view function or pattern name.`, it seems that the piece of code:
`return redirect(request.POST.get('next','dashboard'))` is trying to redirect to `""`.

Which means that when I am accessing `accounts/login`, the `next` variable is not `None` **(because by default `next` is being set as an `empty string` and then being used in the redirect)** so `request.POST.get('next') = ""` and thus it's unable to redirect to`'dashboard'`. I modified my login function as follows:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #some code

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)

            #new code
            if request.POST.get('next') != '':
                return redirect(request.POST.get('next'))
            else:
                return redirect('dashboard')

        else:
            #some code

    else:
        #some code
```

**Extra observation:** If `request.POST.get('next') == "/"` then the page is redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` but `if request.POST.get('next') == ""` then it gives an error `Reverse for "" not found.` because `""` is not a valid view function or URL pattern name.