# Login required always render to home page

Tags: django, django-views

when I am using `login_required` it does not rendering to appropriate url it always render to home page only

login view

```
def login_view(request):
print(request.user.is_authenticated())
w="Welcome"
title = "Login"
form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)        
    messages.success(request, "Successfully Logged In. Welcome Back!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

return render(request, "registration/login.html", {"form":form, "title":title})
```

settings.py file

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

I applied login required on contact us but when i am logging in then it is rendering to home page.

contact us view

```
@login_required
def contactformview(request):
form = ContactForms(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponse(' Thanks For Contacting WIth Us We Will Get Back To You Within 24 Hours')
return render(request, 'contact-us.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: This wont answer your question, but in your form you always think that the website user uses correct credentials...

Comment: Look at the answer of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750464/django-redirect-after-login-not-working-next-not-posting

Answer (score 1):

When Django redirects to the login page, it includes the next url in the querystring, e.g.

```
/login/?next=contact
```

Your `login_view` ignores the querystring and always returns `HttpResponseRedirect("/")`, so you will always be redirected to the homepage.

It would be better to use Django's [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) instead of your own, because it handles the redirect for you. If you must use your own login view, you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L62) to see how Django handles the redirect, and adjust your view.

Comment: when I am logging in it show me /login/?next=contact url but when I get logged in  then it goes to home page

Comment: Yes, as I said, that is because you have `return HttpResponseRedirect("/")` in your code. Please use Django's `login` view instead of trying to write your own. Writing your own can be insecure - as Jingo says, you are currently logging people in whether or not the password is correct.

Comment: Same problem when I used Django's login view

Comment: We can't help if you don't show your view, urls and template.