# Redirecting to originally requested page after login in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django.  I needed to code the login feature to redirect to originally requested URL after login.  I looked around and found the following on a stackoverflow thread.

[django redirect after login not working "next" not posting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750464/django-redirect-after-login-not-working-next-not-posting)

I see the following in the Django documention

> login_required() does the following:
>
> If the user isn’t logged in, redirect to settings.LOGIN_URL, passing
>   the current absolute path in the query string. Example:
>   /accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/.

I also read that the login() method of django.contrib.auth package passes `next` to the template.  So I defined the login() function in my view (I cannot use the one from the 'auth' package since I need some customization).

```
def login(request):
    next = request.GET['next']
    return render(request, 'user/login.html', {'next': next})
```

In my template

```
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'user:login_user' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
<p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input autofocus="" id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" required /></p>
     <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
```

In my login_user() function, if I see that the value of next is present, I redirect to that URL once I have logged the user in.  This works for me fine.

However, solution presented in the thread above was a bit more involved.  I am curious as to why is it necessary to do all that. What am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try changing your

```
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

Comment: Actually, I did not mention properly that my code works fine.  I was curious why you need to do all that proposed in the other thread to get it to work.  I have updated my question.