# Django next redirect to calling form works on localhost but not in production

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue when I want to return to a calling form using a "next" parameter. I have a form with a list of transactions. Clicking on one of the transactions takes me to an update form. After making the update it should return back to the list of transactions. This works fine on my localhost when I run my app using "manage.py runserver". However when I deploy the code to the cloud (Pythonanywhere) clicking the submit button does not return to the calling form but keeps me on the update form.

I've narrowed down the problem to the next parameter dropping the leading slash (/) somewhere along the way in production but not in local host.

tran.html (list of transactions) - this link loads the update form with the transaction to be updated. Here request.get_full_path contains a leading slash ex: '/tran/'

```
<td><a href="{% url 'fin:tran_update' t.id request.get_full_path %}">{{ t.omerchant }}
```

url.py

```
path('tran_update/<int:pk>', views.TranUpdateView.as_view(), name='tran_update'),
path('tran_update/<int:pk>/<path:next>', views.TranUpdateView.as_view(), name='tran_update'),
```

view.py

```
class TranUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = AccountTran
    form_class = AccountTranForm
    template_name = 'fin/tran_update.html'
    context_object_name = 'tran'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        print('get_success_url - in TranUpdateview')
        if 'next' in self.kwargs:
            next_url = self.kwargs['next']
            print('next_url:', next_url)
            return next_url
        return reverse_lazy('fin:tran')
```

When run from production next_url is missing the leading slash ex: 'tran/'. On the local server it has the leading slash ex: '/tran/'.

In production when I click on the submit button in the update view, instead of going back to the list view it stays on the update view and the url changes to:

https://fin.mysite.com/tran_update/4890//tran/tran/

if I click on submit again it changes to:

https://fin.mysite.com/tran_update/4890//tran/tran/tran/tran/

I can't figure out how the leading slash is getting dropped.

I'm using Django 2.2.4, Python 3.8.2 on local and Python 3.7 in the cloud

Comment: Add the code for the relevant forms, You may also want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750464/django-redirect-after-login-not-working-next-not-posting

Comment: I narrowed down the problem to the next parameter dropping the leading slash (/) between the html and the view when run in production. I can't figure out how this is happening in prod but not when run on my local machine in local host. #AzyC

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by checking for a leading slash and adding one if it is missing. This may be fixing a symptom rather than the route problem but it works for now.

```
def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    print('get_success_url - in TranUpdateview')
    if 'next' in self.kwargs:
        next_url = self.kwargs['next']
        if not next_url.startswith('/'):
            next_url = '/' + next_url
        print('next_url:', next_url)
        return next_url
    return reverse_lazy('fin:tran')
```