# Redirecting to actual requested page

Tags: django, django-views

Im trying to access my inner page of my application which has '@login_required () ' enabled so it redirects me to login page., the URL format looks like below

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/user/19/
```

After login is there any configuration which allows me to take it to the actual page that I requested. I have to following code by default. How to redirect to actual page when I got redirected.

```
if user is not None:
                print "Valid user"
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `request.GET['next']`:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next', '/'))
```

Also see: [Django: Redirect to previous page after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login)