# django after login return to last page

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, decorator

If i user is not logged in and encounters a @login_required decorator, it will be send to my login_user view. after login it will be send to my index.  how can I my redirect to the previous page.

```
def login_user(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            if request.POST['next'] != "":
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['next'])
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    #return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form': login_form })
    return render_to_response('login.html', {'login_form': login_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

now i have been looking at: [Django: Redirect to previous page after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login) 
But I'm not sure how to use this, since I don't sent them to login with a link but with a decorator

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">  have that included in the login template inside the login form

Comment: edditing your post to reflect the solution is very good, but better do it in a second codeblock, so people can compare wrong code with right code. I'll upvote your question if you do it :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `login_required` decorator annotates the login-url adding a `next` field to the GET parameters. see [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

e.g. if `LOGIN_URL` is `/login` it becomes `/login?next=/polls/3/vote`

This gets passed to your login view, where you use it

1. To render the login page upon GET or errorneos POST in a request aware manner. Please note that you need to pass the request variables to the template rendercontext. see [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) and [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response).

   ```
   return render_to_response(
           'login.html',
           my_data_dictionary,
           context_instance=RequestContext(request)
   )
   ```
2. in the template add a line like this to the login form

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
   ```
3. Finally upon a succesfull POST use this value to `HttpResponseRedirect`, either to the value of `next` or to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` if no `next` value is present. see [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse).

   ```
   ... user was succesfully authenticated...
   if request.POST["next"] is Not "":
       HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST["next"])
   else:
       HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
   ```

I hope this clarifies things a little bit.

Comment: Right! veto up, that's just what I want to say

Comment: Thanks, i think i grasp the concept better now, and indeed why i get redirected to my login, i get for example: /login/?next=/admin/item/create/   but now im not sure how i give {{ next }} the value /admin/item/create/  (still going to my login_redirect_url)  aslo what is the con of using the render(request, "") shortcut?

Comment: it is done automatically by the `login_required` decorator, just because it's there. Welcome to django magic ;-)

Comment: now i think am a step closer, added the code and hiddne field.  but somehow my {{ next }}  is always empty  (checked with trying to print it)

Comment: as I said in the answer: use `RequestContext` to pass the request variables to your template upon rendering, see the link at the end of the answer.

Comment: okay I will try tho render should force a requestcontext as far as i understood render()
(from django documentation: render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.)

Comment: I also recommend you use `django-debug-toolbar` while developing, it saves you a lot of time in such cases.

Comment: i will take a look at the debugger, thanks for the suggestion (and the help)

Comment: It's not a debugger. It adds a toolbar to your website (while `settings.DEBUG` is `True`). It displays the full rendering context, template paths searched, db queries executed, etc. This saves you from writing debug statements just to check if a context variable is there and what it's value is.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work doing the following:

```
def login_user(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.POST and login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', reverse('index')))

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form': login_form, 'next': request.GET.get('next', '') })
    #return render_to_response('login.html', {'login_form': login_form, 'next': request.GET.get('next', '')}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

also included

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
```

in my login.html  login_form