# django return to index when there is no next= in URL

Tags: django, redirect

i made a login that should redirect to the previous page (with /?next=/)
which seem to work, but when there is no next= it stays on the loginpage without redirecting to the index. Where do i make my mistake?

```
def login_user(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', reverse('index')))
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form': login_form, 'next': request.GET.get('next', '') })
```

My urls.py (in my users app)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from users import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #Authentication urls
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register_user, name='register_user'),
)
```

my urls.py (in my characters app)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

my template: (yes it isn't a beaty, bit old piece of work)

```
{% block content %}
<div>
    <form action="{% url 'login_user' %}" method="post" class="login">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {% if login_form.non_field_errors %}
            <tr>
                <td><i style="font-size: small;">{{ login_form.non_field_errors|striptags }}</i></td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% for field in login_form %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ field }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right;" >
                    <a href="{% url 'register_user' %}">register</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you check that ``reverse('index')`` correctly resolves to your homepage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: Redirect to previous page after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login)

Comment: the #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))   works just fine,

Comment: is your login function working properly?

Comment: yes everything works jsut as it should, except the redirect when there is no ?next=somethuing/ in the url. when there is it redirects jsut fine as well

Comment: could you post your urls.py?

Comment: Could you post your template as well?

Comment: Might be stupid... but did you pdb that ``request.POST.get('next')`` does really fail? Because the default value is only used when the key itself does not exist, not if it's empty.

Comment: if i use request.post.get('next')  then my redirect link is: /login/None

Comment: Okay, then I guess this should be the reason. Could you try instead of using the ``reverse`` as second parameter in the get() function to split that into an if else stmt? ``if request.POST.get('next'): # redirect to next else: # redirecto to reverse('index')``

Comment: with the request.GET.get('next', '') in my render request,  and the if request.POST// else   it works  thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome, the use of ``or`` in @knbk 's answer is more elegant than the if-else though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you don't have a `next` parameter specified in the `GET` parameters, it will be an empty string, but it will still be defined. `request.POST.get('next')` will never fail, but simply return an empty string. You can do the following:

```
def login_user(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next') or reverse('index'))
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form': login_form, 'next': request.GET.get('next', '') })
```

This will return the value of `next`, or `reverse('index')` if that value is empty.