# Django 1.6: Redirect to last page after login not working

Tags: python, django, redirect, authentication

I want the user to be redirected to the last page after successful login whenever the user is prompted to login. Currently, it just redirects to the index page. I know this question has been asked several times and have also tried multiple ways of doing it but it doesnt work. I've also tried following this [Django: Redirect to previous page after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login/1711592#1711592)
and it doesn't work because most of the stuff is already deprecated in 1.6. So I've the following code now and it gives me this `'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.`

on line

`129 :       <h4><a class="writebtn"href=" {% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %} ?next={{request.path}}">Write Review</a></h4>`

This is what i've so far

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'meddy1/login.html'}, name="login")
```

login.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" id="ss-submit">LOG IN</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />

  </form>
```

I've this in my template to see if the user is authenticated to write a review -  if not logged in it renders the login page but then it redirects to the index page

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and reviewed == False %}
      <h4><a class="writebtn"href="/usercontent/{{doctor.id}}/">Write Review</a></h4>

      {% elif user.is_authenticated and reviewed == True  %}
      <h4><a class="writebtn"href="">Already Reviewed!</a></h4>

      {% else %}
      <h4><a class="writebtn"href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">Write Review</a></h4>

      {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def addContent(request, id):
    d = getVariables(request)
    doctor = Doctor.objects.get(id=id)
    params = {}
    params.update(csrf(request))

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        ds = DoctorSeeker.objects.get(user=user)
        d['doctorseeker'] = ds


    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserContentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            time = form.cleaned_data['time']
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']

            if request.POST.get('Like') == 'Like':
                con = UserContent(time=time, comment = comment, liked = True, disliked = False, doctor_id = doctor.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                doctor.likes += 1
                doctor.netlikes = doctor.likes - doctor.dislikes
                doctor.save()
                con.save()

            elif request.POST.get('Like') == 'Dislike':
                con = UserContent(time=time, comment = comment, liked = False, disliked = True,  doctor_id = doctor.id, user_id = request.user.id)
                doctor.dislikes +=1
                doctor.netlikes = doctor.likes - doctor.dislikes
                doctor.save()
                con.save()

            url = '/docprofile/%s' % str(doctor.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    else:
        form = UserContentForm()

    d.update({'doctor': doctor, 'UGC': UserContent.objects.all(),
          'form': form })
    return render(request, 'meddy1/usercontent.html',d)
```

Comment: `{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}`

Comment: Thanks! I don't get the error anymore but it's still not redirecting to the last page.

Comment: Show us your view code.  You're probably not using a `RequestContent`, so won't have a `request` in your template context.

Comment: I've added the view above.

Comment: Okay, you're using a `RequestContext` (via the `render` shortcut) so you must be missing `django.core.context_processors.request`, from your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `settings.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following template code to work:

```
<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">Link</a>
```

The following must be in place:

- You must have a reference to `django.contrib.auth.views.login` in your `urls.py:

  ```
  url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')
  ```
- You must have a template that resolves to `registration/login.html` or you can specify a specific template path (which must exist) in the your url conf:

  ```
  url(r'^login/$',
      'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
      {'template_name': '<your template>'}
      )
  ```
- In your `settings.py`, you must have:

  ```
  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
      'django.core.context_processors.request',
      ...
      )
  ```

  This automatically adds the `request` variable gets to your template context.
- You must render your template with a `RequestContext`.  There are many ways to do that, but the most simple is:

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import render

  def view(request):
      ...
      return render(request, '<template>', {<other context variables>})
  ```

  Using a `RequestContext` causes the `django.core.context_processors.request` context processor  to run.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your detailed answer!