# Dynamic redirect url after login

Tags: django, django-allauth

I need to redirect users after they login to the same page, where they clicked on login link. I use django-allauth.
Just for an examle I will use hardcoded link on one of the pages.

That's what I am trying to do:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
    <a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" next='http://localhost:8000/nominees/detail/63' %}">Facebook</a>
```

Also I tried this way:

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts/facebook/login/' %}?next='http://localhost:8000/nominees/detail/63'">Facebook</a>
```

and this:

```
<a href="accounts/facebook/login?next='http://localhost:8000/nominees/detail/63">Facebook</a>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Refer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login

Comment: Big thanks to Geo Jacob. This works:
<a href="/accounts/facebook/login/?next={{request.path}}">Facebook</a>