# Redirect to previous page after Sign up in view.py : Django 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, redirect, django-views, django-2.0

I build a signup and login page and I want that user after has been signed up or logged in redirect to the page that was been.
this is my views.py :

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                return render(request, 'accounts/SignUp.html',
                              {'error': 'This UserName Has Already Exist, Pleas Try Another UserName.'})
            except:
                user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
                return render(request, 'accounts/SignUp.html',
                              {'error': 'This Email Has Already Registered, Pleas Try Another Email.'})

        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'], email=request.POST['email'],
                                            password=request.POST['pass'],
                                            first_name=request.POST['fname'], last_name=request.POST['lname'])
            auth.login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'StartPage/StartPage.html', {'error': 'Conjurations! You have Signed Up '
                                                                         'Successfully.'})

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/SignUp.html')
```

now how can I make redirect to the page that user has been before clicked for signup?
**In addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login#1711592

Comment: @gizq I checked that link, I want to redirect to previous page in views.py not in my template.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could submit a form with a given URL then retrieve variable in view.py, for example you can use a hidden input and pass current URL as a value:

```
# html
<input type="hidden" name="" value="">

# views.py
request.POST.get('url')
redirect_to_url = request.POST.get('url')
```

You can use the `redirect()` function

```
def singup(request):
    ...
    return redirect(redirect_to_url)
```

Check also [build_absolute_uri()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri), You can get full url using request.build_absolute_uri method.

Comment: Because I’m using {% csrf-token %} I cant get any thing by request.Post.get()

Answer (score 0):

Then, what about this?

It should help.

https://github.com/thoas/django-backward