# Django redirect to login url with next ,without using method decorator

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-login

I have multiple links on my page which redirects user to take quiz.
Some quiz requires user to login or create an account and some does not.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
    
            
    if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
        raise PermissionDenied

    try:
        self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated()
    except TypeError:
        self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated

    if self.logged_in_user:
        self.sitting = Sitting.objects.user_sitting(request.user,
                                                    self.quiz)
    else:
        self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()

    if self.sitting is False:            
        if self.logged_in_user:
            return render(request, self.single_complete_template_name)
        else:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)            
    
    return super(QuizTake, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I would like user to redirect like how method decorator does

```
login/?next=/quiz/f506cb92-ccca-49ff-b2e5-730bbfea6a5a/take/
```

but instead I get `/login/`

I would like my user to come back to the page instead of going to "/dashboard"
In my settings I have

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ="/dashboard"
```

My LoginView:

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = '/dashboard'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect ("/dashboard")
        else:
            return super(LoginView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        if (self.request.user.is_authenticated) and (self.request.user.user_type==4):
            return redirect('/dashboard')
        else:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Use this to add extra context."""       
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'show_captcha' in self.request.session:
            show_captcha = self.request.session['show_captcha']
            context['show_captcha'] = True
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.login(self.request)        
        
        recaptcha_response = self.request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
        payload = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode()
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)

        # verify the token submitted with the form is valid
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
        if result['success']:
            if user.two_factor_auth is False and (user.phone_number_verified is True):
                login(self.request, user) 
                try:
                    UserLog.objects.filter(username=user.id).update(failed_attempt=0)
                except Exception:
                    print("No failed attempts ")
                   
                return redirect('/dashboard')
            
            else:
                try:
                    response = send_verfication_code(user)
                    pass
                except Exception as e:
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR,
                                        'verification code not sent. \n'
                                        'Please retry logging in.')
                    return redirect('/login')
                data = json.loads(response.text)

                if data['success'] == False:
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR,
                                    data['message'])
                    return redirect('/login')

                
                if data['success'] == True:
                    self.request.method = "GET"
                    print(self.request.method)
                    kwargs = {'user':user}
                    return PhoneVerificationView(self.request, **kwargs)
                else:
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR,
                            data['message'])
                    return redirect('/login')
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
            return redirect('/login')
```

Comment: Can you add your login view?

Comment: Added. please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine by using @login_required() decorator docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization).
This appends a ?next=... field which within login field you can take from the request.REQUEST.get('next', '/dashboard') and use this for redirect on successful login also look up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login) to see if any other answer there satisifies the requirements
Also since you don't want decorators you can try saving to session as request.session["next"]=(source url) and within login view get session param and use it