# How to redirect to same page in Django?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

When i am pressing the login button I am getting 404 error even though it is rendered to same page.
The Error is :-

```
Using the URLconf defined in AmazeKart.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
register/ [name='register']
login/ [name='login']
The current path, login/login, didn’t match any of these.
```

Views.py:-

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

URLS.py of app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='register'),
    path('login/', views.login,name='login')
]
```

URLS.py of project

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('User.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Can you show the template that you rendered that has a link?

Comment: Would the solution in the below question work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login?rq=1

Comment: This is the login template
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="box">
<h1>LOGIN</h1>
<form   action="login"  method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="inputbox">
<input type="text" name="username"  required="">
<label>Username</label>
</div>
<div class="inputbox">
<input type="password" name="password"   required="">
<label>Password</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div class="inputbox">
{% for message in messages %}
<h3 style="color:white;">{{message}}</h3>
{%  endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock  %}
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.py write:
`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login/'`

Comment: Can u specify where should I write it cause I had tried writing it below installed apps list it's not working.

Comment: It isn't important the row in the settings.py, but this work only if you use the django built-in login view, [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/), except you have to return from your view `HttpRedirect(path)`.