# Redirect to previous page when login form submitted

Tags: django, django-views, django-users

How would I get the djangos built in LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to redirect to previous page before logging in?

I have tried:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'request.META.HTTP_REFERER'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'request.META.HTTP_REFERER'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Redirect to previous page after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806835/django-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login)